# Parse Issue: Unknown type name 'BOOL'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I suddenly starting get a lot of errors when I build my project. This only happens on the simualtor. The app runs fine on the device. The errors are Parse Issue errors in objc.h, NSObject.h, NSZone.h and then the LLVM compiler gives an error that it's stopping because there are too many errors. The logs show the folling:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:75:9: In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:75:
```

I have tried other solutions online which usually point to a problem with the pch file but no luck. And as I said it works fine on the device but I would like to use the simulator to use the 'capture view hierarchy' debugging feature. Also, this was working on the simulator until these errors suddenly appeared.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem too. In my case the parse issue was related to UInt32 type. I solved it by explicitly adding `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`. This started happening to me when I update XCode to 6. I recommend you to check your dependencies and include any missing library or framework.

Comment: Did you add this import to a specfic class? UIKit is already getting imported in my prefix.pch so it should already be available to all other classes.

Comment: I thought the same, but since I did not add explicitly this framework to my class (that generated the "parse error"), the build wasn't successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The errors are all on Apple classes though, not mine.